# Cannot find readble ctl script

Tags: apache, xampp

I have a problem with **XAMPP on a mac with OS Yosemite 10.10.5**

I have XAMPP installed for while now, tried to start it again but **when launching the manager-osx** that comes with the XAMPP download, I get the following alert:

**Cannot find any readable ctl script**

The result is that I can't start up anything in the manager, therefor I can't start up PhpMyAdmin.

Is there anyone who can help me? I have googled for hours but nothing related seems to come up.

Answer (score 1):

After searching for hours trying to solve this exact issue; whenever I'd try to start OSX Manager it would come up with "Cannot find any readable ctl script", I finally solved my issue!

Somehow the "manager-osx" application was moved from the mediawiki subfolder and into the base Applications folder, so whenever it started it had no idea where any of the settings were. All I had to do was move it back into the folder and boom everything started working again.

Sorry if it's too late for the OP, but hopefully this information is helpful to someone in the future!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I ended up downloading Apache, another fine local host provider!